# Firebase and Angular works sometimes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

Hi I have a problem with angular and firebase 3.0.

When I load view2 nothing happens. If I open the console the message 'welcome' appears ( not always).
I thought it was a console.log problem so I create a new project without use them, but the problem is still here.

This is my code:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.4.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
        apiKey: "................",
        authDomain: "..........firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://.........firebaseio.com",
        storageBucket: ".........appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: ".........."
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
<script src="....angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="....angularfire/2.0.2/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```

---

```
.controller('View1Ctrl', function ($scope) {
var email = "email@email.com";
var password = "password";
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function (error) {
});
```

---

```
.controller('View2Ctrl', function ($scope) {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
        if (user) {
            $scope.a = "welcome";
        } else {

            $scope.a = "who are you";
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok with :

```
 firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) {
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.lung = user.email;
        });
    } else {}

});
```

works.

thx to

> [Why does my Angular's ng-show call only get updated on the second click using Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604921/why-does-my-angulars-ng-show-call-only-get-updated-on-the-second-click-using-fi)

Ps from the link above Frank says:

> A lot of these type of cases are handled automatically if you use the standard binding library: AngularFire.

AngularFire is still available with Firebase 3.0 ?